# Umbraco - use Image Cropper as parameter Type in Macro

Tags: umbraco

I'm using Umbraco 7.4.3 and want to use an Image Cropper data type as a property editor for a Macro. The list of Types presented under the Parameters tab on the Macro does not contain my data type however.

How can I add my custom data type to that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for most default plugins on Umbraco, you just need to add a line in their package.manifest file which is in app_plugin>"addons name">package.manifest

and then add this line

```
isParameterEditor: true,
```

so the file will be like this:

```
{
    propertyEditors: [
        {
        alias: "some name",
        name: "some name",
        **isParameterEditor: true,**
.....
```

you can also read [this article](http://www.nibble.be/?p=415) if you need to create your own

Comment: This answer could be improved with a specific description of where **isParameterEditor: true** is applied. solution/app_plugins doesn't contain a addon folder for the Image Cropper. In order to apply what you've suggested here a custom plugin would need to be added. However, knowing that setting that property to true allows it to be used in the macro is very helpful